# @ManyToMany allowing delete when its not supposed to. Contraint violation

Tags: hibernate, constraints

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = AlunoTO.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "TRE_ALUNO_CURSO", joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name ="id_curso"),     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_aluno"))
private Set<AlunoTO> alunos;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = CursoTreinamentoTO.class)
@JoinTable(name ="TRE_ALUNO_CURSO", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="id_aluno"), inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name ="id_curso") )
private Set<CursoTreinamentoTO> cursos;
```

Curso = Course
Aluno = Students

So this is how I have my @ManyToMany annotated. My problem is, I shouldnt be able to delete Course when theres still a student related to it, but hibernate let me delete that registry without any warnings or errors. Oh yah, I already tried with doing the joinColluns on only one side and doing mappedBy in the other but still doesn´t work.

Why am i able to delete a course when it violates the fk ? Anything wrong with my annotations?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do in the mapping to implement this, as it is very non-standard. For one thing, if you issue a delete statement, you expect either a row to be deleted, or an SQL exception to be reported. If you want to conditionally not delete the row, you'll have to implement that in business logic.